# MySQL order question

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can order a group of users by first 
name and if a user didn't enter a first name 
order that user by last name or if they didn't enter a last name order them by middle name?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
    SELECT fields 
      FROM table 
     WHERE condition 
  ORDER BY first_name, last_name, middle_name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming 'didn't enter' equates to a null field.

```
    SELECT fields  
      FROM table  
     WHERE condition  
  ORDER BY COALESCE(first_name, last_name, middle_name)
```

Comment: `COALESCE(first_name, last_name, middle_name)` ;)

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. Updated answer.

Comment: are you giving 2 examples or just one?

Comment: Removed additional isNull answer as COALESCE is the better option